# Reference request; proof of Banach-Saks for $L^p$ spaces, $1\lt p\lt\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

To be clear, this is the theorem of interest:

> Theorem - Banach-Saks: Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $1\lt p\lt\infty$. If $\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\mathcal{L}^p(X)$ and $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $\mathcal{L}^p(X)$, then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k\in\Bbb N}\subset\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ whose Cesaro mean converges strongly in $\mathcal{L}^p$ to $f$.

Very annoyingly, Royden's real analysis proves this theorem only for $p=2$ and cites another source for the proof with more general $p$. I have been unable to find such a source; all I had found was a sparse proof sketch that a university had posted as homework. I am not a university student however, and as I was struggling with this proof sketch I discovered that the website had gone down. Perhaps this is a temporary issue, but my only resource on this theorem is now lost!

All attempts to google "Banach Saks theorem proof" have resulted in academic papers about the "Banach Saks property", i.e. these papers were proving *other things* with this Banach Saks theorem as an assumption.

From what I could gather from the proof sketch I saw, the details are messy and non trivial for someone with my education to come up with on their own - and that was only the sketch! If anyone knows perhaps a straightforward proof, or a link to a proof, I'd greatly appreciate it! I don't mind if the linked proof is hard or dense, just so long as it's mostly complete. Even hints on proving it for myself would be appreciated; for the reference ability level, I've followed [Royden's book](https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf) (and other [measure theory resources](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/measure_theory)) just fine up until this point.

Links are left for other students such as myself; I believe it is to the user Will Jagy on this site that I owe the pleasure of having Royden's book in the first place!

Comment: "Banach Spaces for analysts", B.Wojtaszczyk, Chapter 3.A, theorem 27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof of the theorem for $p>1$ can be found in Théorème 1 in the original paper by Banach and Saks:

Banach, Stefan, and Stanislaw Saks. "[Sur la convergence forte dans les champs $ L^{p}$.](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm2/sm216.pdf)" Studia Mathematica 2.1 (1930): 51-57.

For a proof in the case $p=1$, you may see

Szlenik, W. "[Sur les suites faiblement convergentes dans l'espace L.](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm25/sm25128.pdf)" Studia Mathematica 25 (1965): 337-341.

Comment: I just read through this, and came back to the site to post it as an answer. For some reason, the English transcription of this was hard to find and quite poorly written, but the French version was well written enough that, even given my weak French and the typos in the text, I could understand the proof in one short sitting

Answer (score 2):

An elegant proof for $L^p-$spaces is provided in Proposition 10.8 (Page 159) in  [Elliptic PDEs, Measures and Capacities From the Poisson Equation to Nonlinear Thomas–Fermi Problems](https://ems.press/books/etm/141)

For a contemporary proof for general banach spaces , you can refer to N. Okada's work in "[On the Banach–Saks property](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-60/issue-7/On-the-Banach-Saks-property/10.3792/pjaa.60.246.full)," published in Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci. 60 (1984), no. 7, pages 246–248.

Another proof for uniformly convex spaces is provided by [Shiztuo KAKUTANI, Weak Convergence in Uniformly Convex Spaces, Tohoku Mathematical Journal, First Series, 1939, 45 p. 188-193](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/45/0/45_0_188/_article/-char/ja/)